# Why does the function return the value of the local JSON variable instead the global?

Tags: javascript, json, global-variables

I have a global JSON variable where I store some parameters and then each time I run the function I want to be able to modify them but just locally inside that function.

So every time I run the function I want a fresh copy of the global variable inside the local one.

The problem is that I copy the global variable to a local one defined in the function, and I make changes to the local variable, but the next time I run the function, instead having an intact copy of the global variable, I am having the one where I have already modified things.

Thanks! :)

```
var test = {"name":"me"};
function bla() {
  var t=test;
  t.name="you";
  t.age=55;
  alert(test.name); // Returns "you" that have been set locally instead of "me" that was global value.
}
bla();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone the object, so that you can modify the clone and leave the original intact... [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2):

Objects are assigned by reference so after

```
var t=test;
```

variables `t` and `test` refer to the same object. You need to make a copy of the object to get the behavior you are looking for. Since you are working with JSON, you could just serialize the original object, then re-parse into a new variable

```
var t = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Then modify the new object as you please

Comment: Going through JSON to clone an object will blast away any non-serializable members (such as functions).

Comment: Read "Since you are working with JSON", then read the title and the body of this question. As long as the object is intended for JSON, serializing and deserializing to clone is likely faster and less error prone than writing a custom recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

`var t = test` does not create a copy of the object. It simply references the same object with another name. If you wish to copy the object, consider using something like jQuery's [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function:

```
var t = $.extend({}, test);
```

While on that topic, the equivalent code for **arrays** is the following:

```
var t = test.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

on your line

```
var t=test;
```

you're not **copying** the contents of `test`, you're creating a new reference to the same content.  therefore, any modification to t's content, modifies test as well.

Answer (score 1):

To copy an arbitrary object to another variable, use a prototype function like this one:

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
  var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
  for (i in this) {
    if (i == 'clone') continue;
    if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
      newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
    } else newObj[i] = this[i]
  } return newObj;
};
```

Usage:

```
var bar = foo.clone();
```

http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165